# I Need Some Help About Axios Lab in JS

Tags: javascript, axios

My issue is:
I need to get some data from an API using `axios` library, but for some cases, it is just not working.

This is a working example:

```java
const RAPIDAPI_API_URL = 'https://cbsservis.tkgm.gov.tr/megsiswebapi.v3/api/parsel/40.89253647288918/29.236472547054294/';
const RAPIDAPI_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
axios.get(RAPIDAPI_API_URL,{ headers: RAPIDAPI_REQUEST_HEADERS })
.then(response => {
    const data = response;
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => console.error('On create error', error));
```

But when the value of `RAPIDAPI_API_URL` is changed to "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", it throws the following error:

```js
Network Error
    at e.exports (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js:2:9633)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.19.2/dist/axios.min.js:2:8398)
```

Comment: When we change it to ```http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users```, it seems to be working. Check here: ```https://repl.it/repls/FavoriteAchingPixels```. Do you mean it doesn't work on tkgm.gov.tr? It seems that tkgm returns xml as a response. You might need to parse that into a js object. Since we don't have access to the responses, we can't debug from here.

Comment: No, actually it works on TKGM but doesn't work on google places API answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the request over https not http. Find sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hypuwx83/)

```
 const RAPIDAPI_API_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
 const RAPIDAPI_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 };

 axios.get(RAPIDAPI_API_URL,{ headers: RAPIDAPI_REQUEST_HEADERS })
   .then(response => {
     const data = response;
     console.log(data);
 })
 .catch(error => console.error('On create error', error));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is work for that link but it is not working for google places API page which is " https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=YOUR_API_KEY" , i have tried it with my API key as http and https, doesn't work

Comment: Are you accessing the API in your browser or on the server? It works when you access the url directly via the browser cos there's no origin when you do that.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, when i use it in browser directly it works but when i use it via "repl.it" in java script code, i can not get details.